# awk and printf inserting extra newline

Tags: bash, awk

I am working on displaying the following file:

```
V   220504203222Z       553A21806C0B711ED9E112E0B6680BED    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=ovpn-server-2020/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
R   220925164608Z 211103011032Z E5D625C06F3D6DA4D3A92C092E8D12A0    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=grom/emailAddress=m2@icloud.com
V   220925165555Z       185B52B7D6ABFF011FB0D7F826DE8851    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=bind9/emailAddress=martinschmid82@icloud.com
V   220925171609Z       8764585492AE0097F76DFD7C9E2E75C7    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a/OU=msc-dev/CN=bind-9/emailAddress=martinschmid82@icloud.com
V   220925171854Z       5B7D28350F750F5745553E0647B79F63    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=qnap/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V   220929131353Z       99E85C7B92BFF646480854B282288E2A    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=ftp/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V   221012163300Z       39403EA3995349FF8FEC487BD59A1F98    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=akaritech.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=masc-mbp/emailAddress=martinschmid82@icloud.com
V   221012163553Z       80668723276AB0B93CF6765F5EA56837    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=akaritech.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=masc-ipad/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V   221016205831Z       7ABD06B289E35D084D19EA170B8F2EC0    unknown /C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=monitoring.brave-vesperia.com/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
```

What I want is the first, second and fifth column separated by a space on the same line. I'm using awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

index="/opt/easy-rsa/easyrsa3/pki/index.txt"

for line in $(awk '{printf "%c %i %s\n", $1, $2, $5} ' ${index}); do
   if ! [[ ${line} =~ ^R.* ]]; then 
      printf "%s\n" $line ; 
   fi 
done
```

However, the output I get is:

```
V
220504203222
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=ovpn-server-2020/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
220925164608
unknown
V
220925165555
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=bind9/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V
220925171609
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=bind-9/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V
220925171854
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=qnap/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V
220929131353
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=ftp/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V
221012163300
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=masc-mbp/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V
221012163553
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=masc-ipad/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
V
221016205831
/C=DE/ST=BY/L=FU/O=a.com/OU=msc-dev/CN=monitoring.brave-vesperia.com/emailAddress=m@icloud.com
```

I don't understand where the extra line breaks are coming from.

Comment: `awk` isn't adding newlines. `for line in ...` loops over the words, not the lines.

Comment: Why are you processing the output of `awk` with a `for` loop? Just do that processing in `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spaces are being added because `for line in $(awk ...)` splits the output of `awk` at whitespace, not newlines.

You could solve this by setting `IFS` to just contain newlines, or pipe `awk` to a `while read line` loop. But it's simpler to just do the whole thing in `awk`.

```
awk '$1 != "R" {printf "%c %i %s\n", $1, $2, $5} ' "${index}"
```